# JAVA - How to trigger when new file come to ftp server

Tags: java, spring-integration

Currently, I have a FTP server that user can upload files to that server and I need to read that files each times user upload. So, how can I create a listener on this?
I'm consider to use spring-integration-fpt, but still not work. can I use apache-common-net?

Comment: Sound like a `WatchService` to me, [check here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<int-file:inboubnd-channel-adapter/>` - see [the Spring Integration File Support documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html).

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for your comments, but this element just help to synchronize with local directory. What I want is just a trigger with the file name. Currently, I use rdp4j to watch directory.

Comment: No; that is incorrect; that's the __<int-ftp__:inbound-channel adapter/>; the __<int-file__:inbound-channel-adapter/> is use to poll a local directory for changes. The upcoming 4.2 release has a [WatchServiceDirectoryScanner](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new.html#_watchservice_directory_scanner).